# Odoo - Find and remove <p> tag

Tags: odoo

I want to remove the `<p>` element:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="helpdesk_support_form_view">
  <field name="name">Helpdesk form</field>
  <field name="model">helpdesk.support</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
      <sheet>
        <group>
          <group>
            <field name="total_spend_hours" widget="float_time" attrs="{'readonly': [('stage_type', '=', 'closed')]}"/>
    
            <p style="color:grey;" colspan="3">Some text here</p>
    
          </group>
        </group>  
      </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

How can I achieve this?

I inherited the view and tried to add:

```xml
  <xpath expr="//p" position="replace">
    <span></span>
  </xpath>
```

But I get this error:

```sh
File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3501, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:184715)
AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: data, line 2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
<xpath expr="//form/sheet/group/group/p" position="replace">
<p></p>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert into string and then use split method to find information.

Following code will work, if have same format for all message / one line < p > tag

```
a = """<p style="color:grey;" colspan="3">Some text here</p>"""
a.split("<p ")[1].split(">")[1].split("</p")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use Odoo XPath, so you need to inherit the base view. your xml code would be something like the following:

```xml
<!-- could be used for qweb templates -->
<template id="custom_template" inherit_id="base_module.base_view">
  <xpath expr="//p" position="replace">
    <span></span>
  </xpath>
</template>
```

if the paragraph in a model view your code could be as following:

```xml
<record id="custom_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">custom.view</field>
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="base_module.base_view"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//p" position="replace">
      <span></span>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

please, note that you must add data inside `xpath` tag. it can't be empty. so add a `span` element as in the provided code.

Comment: don't hesitate to let us know the result> thank you

Comment: could you provide the full base view code and the your view full code as well

Comment: In your XMl file, there is an extra tag. So it gives error as extra content. please provide us with the full inherit view to help.

Comment: I found the solution: `<xpath expr="//form/sheet/group/group/p" position="replace"><p></p></xpath>`